# How to fix cracked wood

Tags: wood, screws

I was putting together a desk which has a wooden surface and metal legs. The wood around the screws joining the wood with the metal leg chipped. How should i fix it?

Comment: Chips and cracks are very different things. Please revise to clarify, and post photos using the editor toolbar if possible.

Comment: Since it's brand new, return it for a refund/replacement. Based on the info you've given us, that's the only info we can give you.

Comment: Are these chips which impact the aesthetic looks of the desk and you want to make it look better, or are these cracks which affect the structural strength of the desk/leg attachment points? Did these defects occur while you were screwing the legs to the desk? Did you use the original screws which were given to you in the assembly kit? Were the holes in the desk for the screws pre-drilled?

Answer (score 1):

Wood glue to hold pieces together with clamps till glue dries.

Maybe a few toothpicks plus glue to fix/fill screw holes.

Pieces of wood/plywood a bit bigger than the tops of the metal legs, glue and screwed under the table where the metal legs mount.